# Increase value on every slider step

Tags: javascript, jquery

Current, I have this function.

```
$(function() {
    $("#rangePoints").change(function() { 
        var qty = $("#rangePoints").val(); 
        var price = $("#price").val();
        $("#qty").val(qty);
        $("#total").val(qty*price/1024);
    });
});
```

And this as the HTML

```
<table>
    <tr>
    <td>Customize RAM</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><input id="rangePoints" type="range" min="1024" max="32768" value="1" step="1024"/><br/><br/></td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Price: </td>
    <td><input id="price" style="width: 50px;" type="text" value="10" readonly /><br/> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
<td>Quantity: </td>
<td><input id="qty" style="width: 50px;" type="text" value="1" readonly /></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>Total Price: </td>
 <td><input type="text" id="total" readonly /></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Currently, what it does is..it multiplies the quantity * price and displays the value in total price field.
What I want is, that the Total price field should be increased by 10 everytime we move one step in the rangepoints slider.

So therefore, the total price for 1024 would be 10, and when we move to next slider value(2048)..the total price should be 20.

What changes are required in the javascript to make it work like this ?

Thanks.

Comment: Multiply by 10 instead of price when calculating the value for the total div?

Comment: looks fine http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/AwPzg/1/

Comment: why dont just add 10 each time to price value and add it into total price field . why are doing such complex stuff of mutiplying and all ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey i have refined your code a bit, its working fine now

**JS CODE:**

```
$(function () {
 $("#rangePoints").change(function () {
    var qty = $("#rangePoints").val();
    var price = $("#price").val();
    var res = qty / 1024;
    $("#qty").val(res);
    $("#total").val(res * price);

 });
});
```

[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/AwPzg/2/) on jsfiddle

*Note: As of now the slider field is not visually a slider,so i guess you need to manually change the values of slider, but the code is fine , when you run with the actual slider component it will work smoothly.*

Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Slider value / 1024 * 10 gives you 10,20,30 until 320 (max slider value 32768)